# Auth0 An error occurred when fetching client data for lock timeout

Tags: auth0

Auth0 login popup is not working on only one machine and returning following error in console

> An error occurred when fetching client data for lock timeout

As this issue is happening on one machine , we cannot debug this locally.
Do anybody have any idea, what are the possible scenarios for this?
Is there any restrictions in Auth0 which could impact any specific user?

Comment: This error indicates that Lock could not connect to the Auth0 CDN to fetch client info. The URL looks something like this: `https://cdn.auth0.com/client/YOUR_CLIENT_ID.js` You might want to check if a browser plugin, etc is preventing this URL from being loaded in this particular machine.